# View ram in DOS

Tags: memory, binary, dos

Is there a way in dos (im using a dos boot disk on a linux machine) to view portions of ram?

ie. some form of command to read the binary at a given address?

edit:  my bootable floppy doesnt have debug on it. when i type debug it says 'bad command or file name

how do i make a bootable dos floppy with debug on it?

Answer (score 2):

Check out the [Debug](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Debug_(command)) command.  There's a good reference [here](http://www.armory.com/~rstevew/Public/Tutor/Debug/debug2.htm)

Answer (score 1):

For the the first 1MB of RAM, `debug` could possibly help.

Answer (score 1):

Use the DOS debug command.  I found a decent overview at: http://mirror.href.com/thestarman/asm/debug/debug.htm